# How to retrieve a data from database and display month wise in view page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a table called Reservation

```
id | property_id | name | checkin_date | checkout_date | guests

1  | 1           | Tim   | 2016-01-10   | 2016-01-15 | 3
2  | 2           | Alex  | 2016-01-16   | 2016-01-26 | 5
3  | 1           | Kevin | 2016-01-28   | 2016-02-10 | 3
```

and so on.

i need to display checkin date and checkout date based on month wise and if date is between two months result should display on both the months ...my expected output in view page is

```
January

2016-01-10 To 2016-01-15 Tim Booked
2016-01-16 To 2016-01-26 Alex Booked
2016-01-28 To 2016-01-31 Kevin Booked

February

2016-02-01 To 2016-02-10 Kevin Booked


March, April,June...etc
```

i already done some partial coding.

in my controller

```
public function index{

    for($i=1; $i<=12; i++){
        $("reservation".$i)=Reservation::whereMonth('checkin_date','=',$i)
                                        ->get();
    }
    return view('abc',compact(reservation1,reservation2));
}
```

and in my view file

```
<h3>January</h3>
<?php foreach($reservation1 as $january){ ?>
<?php echo $january->checkin_date; ?> To <?php echo $january->checkout_date; ?> <?php echo $january->name; ?> Booked
```

please someone help me to get output...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need this library [FullCalendar](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)

Controller

```
public function test(){
    $events = [];
    //creating events
    $events[] = \Calendar::event(
        'Angel', //event title
        true, //full day event?
        '2016-01-01', //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        '2016-01-03', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        1, //optionally, you can specify an event ID
        [
            'backgroundColor' => '#ff5722'
        ]
    );
    $events[] = \Calendar::event(
        'Jesus', //event title
        true, //full day event?
        '2016-01-04', //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        '2016-01-08', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
        1, //optionally, you can specify an event ID
        [
            'backgroundColor' => '#e97118'
        ]
    );
    //adding events
    $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)->setOptions(['lang' => 'es']);

    return view('pages.calendar')->with('calendar',$calendar);
}
```

View (it's better to use blade)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
        {!! $calendar->script() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

result
[image]

Comment: Thank you @user2958452. this wasn't the answer i was looking for.. okay lets make it simple to understand, i need to show all the dates that are booked for every single month. lets say a user is booking from January 28th to February 5th i should be able to show the dates booked till January end and the rest in the month of February. #sorry for my poor english

Comment: i have edited the question for better knowledge.. it would be great if someone could enlighten me on this query :/

Comment: @laktherock Now I understand what you want, You can do it by using [full-calendar](https://packagist.org/packages/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar), I hope this is the approach you are looking for